# How to perform '%' in my MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql

I use https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL to connect with MySQL. I want to perform a "like" query in a MySQL command.

Below is the command:

```
"select * from table where c1 > '2015-11-01' and c2 not like '%word%'"
```

I have a table `table` which has columns c1, c2, and c3.

```
import pymysql.cursors
def query_my(my_query):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='',
                             user='',
                             passwd='',
                             db='',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
        sql = "select c3 from table where c1 > %s and c2 not like '%word%'"
        cursor.execute(sql, (my_query))
        re = cursor.fetchall()
        return re
        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close() 
my_query='2015-11-01'
query_my(my_query)
```

and it will return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/y/share/htdocs/cgi/weekly_report_v2.py", line 31, in <modul
    print query_inc_group(i_start,i_stop)
  File "/home/y/share/htdocs/cgi/weekly_report_v2.py", line 18, in query_inc_group
    cursor.execute(sql, (_i_start,_i_stop))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.6-py2.6.egg/pymysql/cursors.py", line 143, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.6-py2.6.egg/pymysql/cursors.py", line 134, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I think the problem is from `not like '%word%'`. How do I fix this kind of error? I have printed SQL directly, and the result looks good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put two % to escape it.

```
"select c3 from table where c1 > %s and c2 not like '%%word%%'"
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.6-py2.6.egg/pymysql/cursors.py", line 134, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)

This line causes the error because it uses python String format to replace your parameters in the sql.

Comment: It works! But why? a kind of escape way? I have printed 'sql', it show %% double %

Comment: saved my day. single % works perfectly in local but when deployed to server it throw exception. i don't know why but it works with python fastapi . thanks.